# "Gateway error: (TESTMODE) The merchant login ID or password is invalid or the account is inactive.During PlaceOrder Authorised.net in magento"

Tags: e-commerce, payment-gateway, magento-1.5, authorize.net

I am facing error during the placeorder using method authorised.net in magento:

```
"Gateway error: (TESTMODE) The merchant login ID or password is invalid or the account is inactive.
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was having this exact same problem.  I used the information here to solve the problem:

http://support.authorize.net/authkb/index?page=content&id=A415&pmv=print&impressions=false

The short answer is that you need to change the Gateway URL from the default (that you would use with a real account):

https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll

to (use with your test account):

https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll

To do this in the Magento Dashboard:

1. Go to System -> Configuration
2. Select Sales -> Payment Method (in the left sidebar)
3. Expand the "Authorize.net" option (I didn't try the "Authorize.Net Direct Post" option, but it appears to use the same default Gateway URL, so this will probably work with that, too).
4. Change the "Gateway URL" from the default Gateway URL to the test Gateway URL (see above).
5. Click "Save Config" at the top.
6. Retry your test sale--it should work now!

Answer (score 16):

This happened to me as well, so for posterity:

If you are still using the test gateway, there is a pre-set API Login ID: 92KgL2uD and Transaction Key: 4nT73z4473vLJfXF.

Then when you move to production code, you will need to use the API Login ID and Transaction Key available through the Merchant Profile.

Comment: The API keys worked for me during testing. Thanks @Reed.

Comment: @reed can you share please MD5

Answer (score 1):

Please, use https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll to 'Gateway URL'  for the test transaction.

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You will get this error for the following reasons:

1. Either your login ID or transaction key is wrong.
2. You're trying to use the developer account with your live credentials or vice versa
3. Your Authorize.Net account is inactive

Comment: I am not using developer account with my live credentials. i have also check that Authorized.net accont is active.

Comment: @user1194332 - did you solve this issue? I'm having the same problem.